# How to implement favorite button in tableView cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I need to implement a save button. When a user taps on the button, it has to be filled, by default it's unfilled. But when I run my app some of the buttons in tableView cell are already filled [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH9aH.jpg)

Here's code from TableViewCell

```
var isFavorite: Bool = false

private let addToFavorites: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "heart"), for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.85)
    button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
    return button
}()

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    
    setFavoriteButtonUI()
    addToFavorites.addTarget(self, action: #selector(markFavorite), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func markFavorite() {
    setFavoriteButtonImage()
}

private func setFavoriteButtonImage() {
        isFavorite = !isFavorite
        let imgName = isFavorite ? "heart" : "heart.fill"
        let favoriteButtonImage = UIImage(systemName: imgName)
        self.addToFavorites.setImage(favoriteButtonImage, for: .normal)
    }

private func setFavoriteButtonUI() {

    addToFavorites.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(addToFavorites)
    
    addToFavorites.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filmImgView.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    addToFavorites.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filmImgView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    addToFavorites.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    addToFavorites.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
}
```

In cellForRowAt indexPath method I added

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.top)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a classical problem for iOS beginners.

`TableViewCell` has a mechanism of reusing object pool.

When some cell with filled heart slides off the screen, the cell enters the reusing object pool.

The new cell appeared on the screen, maybe is created, or pulled from the reusing object pool.

---

The simple solution is `Mark & Config`.

Just to maintain the cell status data out the scope of cell, we usually have the  status data source on the controller.

`@objc func markFavorite()` changes the status data source, then `table` reload data.

in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` , config the cell heart status.

---

in Controller:

```
var selected = [Int]()


func select(index idx: Int){
   selected.append(idx)
   table.reloadData()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    // ...
    cell.proxy = self
    cell.config(willShow: selected.contains(indexPath.row), idx: indexPath.row)

}
```

in Cell:

```
var proxy: XXXProxy? // learn sth proxy yourself

var idx: Int?

func config(willShow toShow: Bool, idx index: Int){
     idx = index
     btn.isHidden = !toShow
}

// add the rest logic yourself
```

Comment: Thank you for trying me to help. Do you mean that I should call .addTarget  in cellForRow method and selector in tableView controller? I tried this: cell.addToFavorites.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MoviesViewController.markFavorite), for: .touchUpInside) and in selector: @objc func markFavorite() {
        isFavorite = !isFavorite
        let imgName = isFavorite ? "heart" : "heart.fill"
        let favoriteButtonImage = UIImage(systemName: imgName)
        cell.addToFavorites.setImage(favoriteButtonImage, for: .normal)
        tableView.reloadData()
        }

Comment: Now all buttons are unfilled but If I tap on button it can't be filled :(

Comment: refreshed.  add the rest logic yourself

Comment: I don't mean to call .addTarget in cellForRow method and selector in tableView controller

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here is sth you can learn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028109/new-view-created-with-every-collectionview-cell-tap-instead-of-updating-the-exis/65031401#65031401

Comment: here u can get some idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328299/reload-tableview-after-clicking-the-button-present-inside-one-of-the-tableview-c/64330243#64330243

Comment: This question is quite old fashioned. The solution is just a pattern `mark & config`